# How to Use or Create Hmac SHA256 in Online Excel Typescript Editor

Tags: javascript, excel, typescript, sha256, hmac

We have a weather station that sends all its data to the manufacturers servers and allows API calls.

I have stumbled my way through creating a google apps script that successfully retrieves current weather conditions every 15 minutes and populates it in to a google spreadsheet. But we are wanting to use Microsoft Power BI to do analysis of this data for various reasons. So for ease of compatibility I want to recreate this in Microsoft Excel Online instead of having it in Google sheets.

And the part that I am stuck on is the hashing of certain collected parameters that the servers require for authentication. Specifically the Hmac SHA256 part. In Google App Script I have this:

```js
 var APISignature = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(StringToHash,APISecret);
  APISignature = APISignature.map(function(e) {return ("0" + (e < 0 ? e + 256 : e).toString(16)).slice(-2)}).join("");
```

(Which thankfully I was able to find online and to be honest I do not fully understand the mapping part of it)

Is there similair method or function that is available in Online Excel Typescript?